# Why doesn't OpenVPN Client start when Windows boots?

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, openvpn, task-scheduler

I own my own private OpenVPN server and serves to encrypt my connection, as well as giving access to private file storage on the VPS that hosts the OpenVPN server.

Due to this, I want the OpenVPN client application to connect automatically when Windows boots, as to ensure no gap in the encrypted connection (I made a small application that stops any data being sent/received, in the case the OpenVPN connection fails).

I followed the instructions to do so [here](http://www.personalvpn.org/auto_login_openvpn.htm) (admittedly, when the user logs on), but the OpenVPN client application doesn't start:

[image]

I then [followed the instructions here](https://help.my-private-network.co.uk/support/solutions/articles/8464-windows-openvpn-auto-start) to schedule that the OpenVPN client starts on log-on, also with no such luck:

[image]

[image]

but however I did notice that the `openvpn-gui` (OpenVPN client) *does* however exist on Task Manager's 'Startup' tab:

[image]

This leads me to believe that this could be the fault of the OpenVPN client program; on every boot (at the moment) I manually start the OpenVPN client program, and connect to my OpenVPN server.

How can I correctly make the OpenVPN client start-up and connect, on either log-on, or before log-on?

Comment: @Arjan Apparently there's been a few MS Office spam seeds in the last few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue surrounds that I have a 64 bit system, meaning OpenVPN client was installed in `Program Files`, as opposed to `Program Files (x86)`; simply changing from `Program Files (x86)` to `Program Files` fixed this issue.

Comment: As an aside: nothing in the Windows Event Viewer for it not being able to find the erroneous path?

Comment: @Arjan Didn't think of that, I'll check.

Comment: in my case sometimes it starts sometimes doesn't on system startup, I use it to manage remote servers that are behind nat. I have to connect with TV and do a manual re-run of the scheduled task (that is actually running) to make it work. did you manage to find a 100% success way for Startup?